# Install Softwares

Tags: software-installation

I have downloaded software in download folder.How can I install it?

I created /Home and / partition in ubuntu.Let me know what is the partition this software is going to install?

Comment: Ordinarily Ubuntu software is not installed by downloading.  Most of the time when I am asked this by friends new to ubuntu, they are trying to install software not compatible with Ubuntu.  It would help us to help you if you could name the software you are trying to install.

Comment: @gyropyge im going to  install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for replying to my comment.  Please install the software in the conventional manner using the Ubuntu Software Center.  [THIS LINKED PAGE](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/adobe-flashplugin/) includes a button that expedites the process.

Comment: Thank you.Can u give me answer for my second question?

Comment: I don't know enough about your installation to tell you where your software will install.  I would assume that if you install your software in the conventional manner, it will install in the conventional location in your home folder.  I've never particularly tried to install software in unconventional locations.  How experienced are you with Ubuntu?

Comment: about 5 hours.,

Comment: I see.  Let me assure you that your experience with Ubuntu can be fun and easy or difficult and challenging.  If you follow my lead it will be fun and easy.  I have more than 10 years experience, and I've composed many guides to even some of the most difficult procedures.  I even have a guide to installing Microsoft Internet Explorer in Ubuntu, but I advise against doing so.

Comment: Maybe if you could explain to me why it matters to you where the software will install physically.  Most people don't ask that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide more information.  Did you download a .deb package?  Did you download source code?

- Assuming you downloaded a .deb file you should install the software by following this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line).
- Assuming you downloaded source code for a large project.  Uncompress it in your where ever you downloaded it. Then build it usually by typing" ./configure in a terminal.  When that complete type: make.  When that finishes typically typing: sudo make install will copy the binaries to the proper directories.
- If it is something else, more information is required.

Good luck

Comment: Follow gyropyge's link.

Comment: No.I downloaded tar.gz file